# Pair-wise equality over large sets of large vectors

Tags: performance-tuning, permutation

I've got an interesting performance tuning/algorithmic problem that I'm running into in an optimization context.

I've got a set of ~16-50 lists of integers (usually in `Range[0, 5]` but no restricted to that).
The data might look like this (although obviously not random)

```
maxQ = 5;
ndim = 16;
nstates = 100000;
braVecs = RandomInteger[{0, maxQ}, {ndim, nstates}];
ketVecs = braVecs + RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {ndim, nstates}];
```

now for every element `q ∈ Subsets[ndim, 4]` I need to determine where every pair of `braVecs` and `ketVecs` are the same, *except* for the indices in `q`, i.e. I for every possible `q` I need to calculate this

```
qComp = Complement[Range[ndim], q];
diffs = braVecs[[qComp]] - ketVecs[[qComp]];
Pick[Range[nstates], Times @@ (1 - Unitize[diffs]), 1]
```

Just as an example, this is the kind of thing I expect to get out

```
q = RandomSample[Range[ndim], 4];
qComp = Complement[Range[ndim], q];
diffs = braVecs[[qComp]] - ketVecs[[qComp]];
{q, Pick[Range[nstates], Times @@ (1 - Unitize[diffs]), 1]}

{{2, 9, 6, 4}, {825, 1993, 5577, 5666, 9690, 9856, 11502, 13515, 15680, 18570, 
  19207, 23131, 26986, 27269, 31889, 39396, 39942, 51688, 52520, 54905, 55360, 
  60180, 61682, 66258, 66458, 68742, 71871, 78489, 80906, 90275, 91520, 93184}}
```

This can obviously be done just by looping, but I *sure* there is an algorithmically more efficient way to do this, maybe using a Trie or maybe using some Boolean algebra to reuse prior calculations? This is important because my `ndim` can get up to ~50 and there are a huge number of elements in `Subsets[50, 4]`... I just don't know what the best way to approach this kind of thing is.

Comment: `Pick[Range[nstates], Total@diffs, 0]` and `Pick[Range[nstates], Plus@@diffs, 0]` seems to be slightly faster.

Comment: @kglr I probably should add some clarification, but the main issue is just evaluating that efficiently over every q. My guess is speeding up evaluation of that expression won’t pay much in the way of dividends

Answer (score 4):

Interesting problem. The best I have been able to come up so far is this:

```
diffdata = Unitize[Subtract[braVecs, ketVecs]];
diffcounts = Total[diffdata];
F = q \[Function] Random`Private`PositionsOf[
    Plus[
     diffcounts,
     SparseArray[Partition[q, 1] -> -1, ndim, 0].diffdata
     ],
    0
    ];
```

For `ndim = 50`, the timings on my machine are as follows:

```
q = RandomSample[Range[ndim], 4];
t1 = N@First@RepeatedTiming[
    qComp = Complement[Range[ndim], q];
    diffs = braVecs[[qComp]] - ketVecs[[qComp]];
    aa = Pick[Range[nstates], Times @@ (1 - Unitize[diffs]), 1];
    ]
t2 = N@First@RepeatedTiming[bb = F[q];]
aa == bb
t1/t2
```

> 0.103461
>
> 0.00156106
>
> True
>
> 66.2757

**Explanation**

My first observation in the original code was that each component of `Unitize[braVecs[[qComp]] - ketVecs[[qComp]]]` was recomputed for each `q`. Thus I refactored so that `diffdata` is computed only once.

The next observation was that `Times @@ (1 - Unitize[diffs])` requires `(ndim -Length[q]-1) nstates` multiplications. My first step was to try to replace the multiplications by additions (On recent CPUs, multiplication and addition are equally fast, but my old Haswell has one of the last ones with dedicated addition pipelines.) But then I realized that I can make it only `(Length[q]-1) nstates` additions by precompting diffcounts and by subtracting `Total[diffdata[[q]]]`. This becomes more and more advantageous in increasing `ndim`.

However, `diffdata[[q]]` intruces a copy operation that I preferred to avoid. This is why I use

```
SparseArray[Partition[q, 1] -> -1, ndim, 0].diffdata
```

instead of `Total[diffdata[[q]]]`.

The undocumented function `` Random`Private`PositionsOf `` does the same as `Pick` here, but is a bit faster (because it does not have to create `Range[nstates]`, first.

**Final Remark**

Afterall, your biggest problem is to store all the results. Even with only `ndim = 16`, my laptop had to give up (16 GB of RAM + compression + swapping).

Comment: I handle each result as it comes out, so happily I never need to store all of them at once. I really like the trick to avoid doing `Total[diffdata[[q]]]`. Is there a way to apply that to what I'm doing with my trie stuff? I.e. can `Pick[trie["idx"], diffdata[[i, trie["idx"]]], 0]` or `Pick[initInds, Plus @@ diffdata[[qRest, initInds]], 0]` be rewritten using that idea?

Answer (score 2):

I realized that building a partial prefix trie could actually have significant benefits if done right.
There are twos key realizations:

1. by the time you've computed the set of indices that agree over 4 of the dimensions, the number of remaining indices to compare drops by ~1/16th
2. since `Complement[Range[ndim], q]` is sorted, every prefix string will start with either 1, 2, 3, or 4, except for a single term starting with 5. This allows us to compute a significantly smaller number of prefixes and still get the benefit of the pre-computation.

The downside, of course, is that the code to build the prefix trie is more involved.
First we define a function to refine our set of indices based on including the next set of pair-wise equalities. We precompute `diffdata` just as Henrik did.

```
diffdata = Unitize[Subtract[braVecs, ketVecs]];
pullSubtrieInds[trie_, i_] :=
 Pick[trie["idx"], diffdata[[i, trie["idx"]]], 0]
```

Next we have a function to recursively build out most of the trie

```
constructSubtrie[trie_, i_, depth_, maxDepth_] :=
  Module[{newTrie = trie},
   newTrie[i] = <|"idx" -> pullSubtrieInds[trie, i]|>;
   If[depth < maxDepth,
    Do[
     newTrie[i] = constructSubtrie[newTrie[i], j, depth + 1, maxDepth];,
     {j, i + 1, ndim}
     ]
    ];
   newTrie
   ];
```

and now we add a small modification to add the remaining prefix starting with `5`, which simply doesn't loop as much

```
addFinalSubtrieElem[trie_, i_, depth_, maxDepth_] :=
  Module[{newTrie = trie},
   newTrie[i] = <|"idx" -> pullSubtrieInds[trie, i]|>;
   If[depth < maxDepth,
    newTrie[i] = constructSubtrie[newTrie[i], i + 1, depth + 1, maxDepth];
    ];
   newTrie
   ];
```

and then we can build the total trie like

```
constructSubtrie[trie_, maxDepth_] :=
  (* 
  after doing the complement operation, 
  we get lists of indices that are at minimum ndim-4 elements long, 
  so after sorting
  they all must contain 1 through 5 at some point and the one with the 5 only \
occuring once, so we just compute that one directly... *)
  
  Module[{newTrie = trie, subtrie},
   Do[
    newTrie = constructSubtrie[newTrie, i, 1, maxDepth], 
    {i, 4}
    ];
   (* add on the single set of indices that can start with 5 *)
   
   addFinalSubtrieElem[newTrie, 5, 1, maxDepth]
   ] ;
```

The trie itself is a bit slow to build at `ndim=25`

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  $preindexTrieDepth = 4;
  $preindexTrie = 
   constructSubtrie[<|"idx" -> Range[nstates]|>, $preindexTrieDepth];
  ][[1]]

2.93388
```

but could be made faster or slower based on using a larger/smaller `$preindexTrieDepth`. We'll still see a payoff in the end.

Next we have a function that actually uses this trie to pull indices

```
getSubsetDiffs[q_, prefTrie_, prefTrieDepth_] :=
 Module[{qComp = Complement[Range[ndim], q], initInds, qRest},
  initInds = prefTrie[Sequence @@ qComp[[;; prefTrieDepth]]]["idx"];
  qRest = qComp[[1 + prefTrieDepth ;;]];
  Pick[initInds, Plus @@ diffdata[[qRest, initInds]], 0]
  ]
```

and now some timing comparisons

```
getSubsetDiffsOG[q_] :=
 Random`Private`PositionsOf[
  Plus @@ diffdata[[qComp]], 
  0
  ]
AbsoluteTiming[
  Do[
   getSubsetDiffsOG[q],
   {q, subsets}
   ]
  ][[1]]

40.5721

diffcounts = Total[diffdata];
F = q \[Function]
   Random`Private`PositionsOf[
    Plus[diffcounts, SparseArray[Partition[q, 1] -> -1, ndim, 0].diffdata], 0];
AbsoluteTiming[
  Do[
   F[q],
   {q, subsets}
   ]
  ][[1]]

19.7401

AbsoluteTiming[
  Do[
   getSubsetDiffs[q, $preindexTrie, $preindexTrieDepth],
   {q, subsets}
   ]
  ][[1]]

5.81803
```

which shows a factor of ~7 speedup over the totally naive method and a factor of ~3 speedup over Henrik's approach, after accounting for the time required to build the trie.

```
40.572074`/(5.818029`+2.93388)

6.97351

19.7401`/(5.818029`+2.93388)

3.39292
```

Finally to confirm that things are coming out right

```
Catch[
 Do[
  If[Total[F[q] - getSubsetDiffs[q, $preindexTrie, $preindexTrieDepth]] > 0, 
   Throw[False]
   ],
  {q, Subsets[Range[ndim], {4}]}
  ];
 True
 ]

True
```

This could also likely be made faster by using Henrik's indexing strategy. I'm currently just doing naive subsampling of `diffdata` and using a `Pick` call.

---

#### Full Code Block

```
diffdata = Unitize[Subtract[braVecs, ketVecs]];
pullSubtrieInds[trie_, i_] :=
 Pick[trie["idx"], diffdata[[i, trie["idx"]]], 0]
ClearAll[constructSubtrie]
constructSubtrie[trie_, i_, depth_, maxDepth_] :=
  Module[{newTrie = trie},
   newTrie[i] = <|"idx" -> pullSubtrieInds[trie, i]|>;
   If[depth < maxDepth,
    Do[
     newTrie[i] = constructSubtrie[newTrie[i], j, depth + 1, maxDepth];,
     {j, i + 1, ndim}
     ]
    ];
   newTrie
   ];
addFinalSubtrieElem[trie_, i_, depth_, maxDepth_] :=
  Module[{newTrie = trie},
   newTrie[i] = <|"idx" -> pullSubtrieInds[trie, i]|>;
   If[depth < maxDepth,
    newTrie[i] = constructSubtrie[newTrie[i], i + 1, depth + 1, maxDepth];
    ];
   newTrie
   ];
constructSubtrie[trie_, maxDepth_] :=
  (* 
  after doing the complement operation, 
  we get lists of indices that are at minimum ndim-4 elements long, 
  so after sorting
  they all must contain 1 through 5 at some point and the one with the 5 only \
occuring once, so we just compute that one directly... *)
  
  Module[{newTrie = trie, subtrie},
   Do[
    newTrie = constructSubtrie[newTrie, i, 1, maxDepth], 
    {i, 4}
    ];
   (* add on the single set of indices that can start with 5 *)
   
   addFinalSubtrieElem[newTrie, 5, 1, maxDepth]
   ] ;
getSubsetDiffs[q_, prefTrie_, prefTrieDepth_] :=
 (* we assume sorting *)
 
 Module[{qComp = Complement[Range[ndim], q], initInds, qRest},
  initInds = prefTrie[Sequence @@ qComp[[;; prefTrieDepth]]]["idx"];
  qRest = qComp[[1 + prefTrieDepth ;;]];
  Pick[initInds, Plus @@ diffdata[[qRest, initInds]], 0]
  ]
```