# Fastest way to do repeated subsample/Intersection calls over large set of vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

In this answer I found I needed to calculate a bunch of intersections of subsets of vectors, like

```
Clear[takeSubpspaceIntersections];
takeSubpspaceIntersections[i_, pos_, val_, perms_] :=
 Block[{
   subperms, picked = Range[Length[perms]],
    badPickI, badListsI,
   badPickJ, badListsJ,
   fullInds,
   badVals, balValIndMap, badPosJ,
   bad1
   },
  subperms = perms[[picked]];
  badPickI = Pick[Range[Length[perms]], perms[[;; , i - 1]], val];
  fullInds = Range[Length[perms[[1]]]];
  Do[
   badPickJ = Pick[Range[Length[picked]], subperms[[;; , j]], val];
   If[Length[badPickJ] > 0,
    (* 
        subsample set of input vectors, take their intersectiom
    *)
    badListsI = perms[[badPickI, Delete[fullInds, i - 1]]];
    badListsJ = subperms[[badPickJ, Delete[fullInds, j]]];
    badVals = Intersection[badListsJ, badListsI];
    
    (* 
        remap intersected vectors to corresponding elements of badPickJ
        and resample input vectors
    *)
    balValIndMap = AssociationThread[badListsJ, badPickJ ];
    badPosJ = Lookup[balValIndMap, badVals];
    picked = picked[[ Complement[Range[Length[picked]], badPosJ] ]];
    subperms = perms[[picked]]
    ],
   {j, pos}
   ];
  subperms
  ]
```

The problem is that this can be slow over large numbers of vectors

```
perms1000 =
  BlockRandom[SeedRandom[4];
    RandomInteger[3, {1000000, 15}]] // DeleteDuplicates;

(spint = takeSubpspaceIntersections[5, {2}, 1, perms1000];) // 
  RepeatedTiming // First

0.83
```

Some preliminary testing suggests that the slowest part is the number of times I'm doing things like `perms[[badPickI, Delete[fullInds, i - 1]]];` which because of the way Mathematica handles tensors internally forces a copy.

Is there a way I can make this subsample/Intersection process faster, maybe by doing the `Intersection` piece-by-piece over the intersection of `Delete[fullInds, i - 1]` and `Delete[fullInds, j]` first, allowing me to iteratively refine the result over smaller chunks of memory? (kinda similar to the ideas here: [Pair-wise equality over large sets of large vectors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240967/pair-wise-equality-over-large-sets-of-large-vectors))